# Haskell Tree With Function Branches

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'll start of by saying I'm very new to Haskell, so I haven't learned about things like Monads yet.

In Haskell I'm trying to make a type of tree that has numbers as the leaves and functions as the branches so the whole tree can act kind of like a calculator.

Here's my code so far. Currently instead of having functions as an input I'm just using characters.

```
data Tree3 = Leaf3 Int | Node3 Char Tree3 Tree3 deriving (Show)
-- I would like to replace this ^  Char somehow with a function.

evaluate :: Tree3 -> Int
evaluate (Leaf3 x) = x
evaluate (Node3 c m n) | c == '+'    = evaluate m + evaluate n
                       | c == '-'    = evaluate m - evaluate n
                       | c == '/'    = evaluate m `div` evaluate n
                       | c == '*'    = evaluate m * evaluate n
```

So my question is can I have an input of a function in the data structure (and what would the type be?)

Sorry for the probably confusing question, but thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend writing your tree as:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node (Int -> Int -> Int) Tree Tree
```

Note that you won't be able to derive `Eq` or `Show`, since `Int -> Int` doesn't implement either of those typeclasses (and it's <strike>impossible</strike> **impractical** to do so).

Then you can write your `evaluate` function as

```
evaluate :: Tree -> Int
evaluate (Leaf x) = x
evaluate (Node f l r) = f (evaluate l) (evaluate r)
```

which is much simpler!

You can make a tree to represent an expression like `(1 + 2) * (3 * 4)` as

```
expr :: Tree
expr = Node (*) (Node (+) (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Node (*) (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))
```

---

Another way that would make it easier to prettier print your tree would be to use almost the same definition you have:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node String Tree Tree
--                          ^ String instead of Char
```

Then if you have `Data.Map` imported, you can create a map of functions to look up, but it makes your `evaluate` function a bit more complex since you introduce the possibility that your function won't be in your map.  Luckily Haskell has some really handy tools for handling this elegantly!

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Tree = Leaf Int | Node String Tree Tree deriving (Eq, Show)

type FuncMap = Map.Map String (Int -> Int -> Int)

evaluate :: FuncMap -> Tree -> Maybe Tree
evaluate funcs (Leaf x) = return x
evaluate funcs (Node funcName left right) = do
    -- Use qualified import since there's a Prelude.lookup
    f <- Map.lookup funcName funcs
    l <- evaluate funcs left
    r <- evaluate funcs right
    return $ f l r
```

This will automatically result in `Nothing` if you try something like

```
evaluate (Map.fromList [("+", (+))]) (Node "blah" (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2))
```

since the function `"blah"` isn't in your `FuncMap`.  Notice how we didn't have to do any explicit error handling of any kind thanks to `Maybe`'s monad instance!  If any of the lookups to the function map return `Nothing`, the whole computation returns `Nothing` without us having to think about it.

Comment: `Eq` and `Show` instances for `Int -> Int -> Int` [aren't impossible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Reverse.html) (note the `a -> b` instances for these classes), just impractical.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, you can actually make instances, but in practice there isn't much use for them.  Most people would want something like `Eq (Int -> Int -> Int)` so that they can do something like `if (+) == (+) then ... else ...`, but that just doesn't work in Haskell.  While somewhat inaccurate, I wanted to direct readers away from thinking that they could compare functions in what I would call the "human" sense of equality.  Truly, an instance could be defined as `instance Eq (a -> b) where _ == _ = True` or alternatively with `False`, but this still has no practical use.

Comment: The instance provided in my link actually does correctly compare for semantic equality, not just `_ == _ = True`. But I freely admit that despite its correctness it is still impractical -- the comparison `(+) == (+)` would invoke `(==) :: Int -> Int -> Int` some 2^128 times on a 64-bit machine!

Comment: But notably, anything with a small domain can be fairly efficiently checked. It's sort of mind blowing the first time you realize that `Bool -> a` is `(a, a)`. Morally.

Comment: Use a wrapper: `newtype ShownAs a = ShownAs a String; use (ShownAs a _) = a; instance Show (ShownAs a) where show (ShownAs _ s) = s;`  Then your larger type can still use `deriving`.